# Replace the whole string in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

I have a list of tokens. Some start with an `@` sign. I want to change all those strings to a generic `@user`. I have tried this:

```
>>> words = ['@john', 'nina', 'michael', '@bebeto']
>>> words = [w.replace(w, '@user') for w in words if w.startswith('@')]
>>> words
['@user', '@user']
>>>
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I'd think `['@user', 'nina', 'michael', '@user']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can simplify the first part of the list comprehension. This is equivalent and doesn't do a needless replacement:

```
words = ['@user' for w in words if w.startswith('@')]
```

In a list comprehension, the if clause at the end decides what is included or not. So the if basically says, only keep elements which starts with '@'. But you want to keep all elements.

Instead you can use a conditional expression to decide whether to get '@user' or the original word:

```
words = ['@user' if w.startswith('@') else w for w in words]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your list comprehension is causing the undesired output, just change

```
[w.replace(w, '@user') for w in words if w.startswith('@')]
```

To

```
[w.replace(w, '@user') if w.startswith('@') else w for w in words]
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax in Python. See other answers for correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
words = ['@john', 'nina', 'michael', '@bebeto']
new_words = ['@user' if i.startswith('@') else i for i in words]
```

Output:

```
['@user', 'nina', 'michael', '@user']
```